# Passing data from the class to the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting a Service `TrackingService` from MainActivity in the `onCreate()`. From the `TrackingService` I am passing `JSONString` to the `PostData` class. Then I am getting a Response from the server with the `direction, route`. I want to pass these values to the MainActivity but I am not getting them in the MainActivity. direction and route have values and `onPostExecute()` is being invoked and this condition `if (route != 0) {}` in the method is being entered but the ´onNewIntent()´ method in the MainActivity is not being invoked. How can I fix it to get the direction and route in the `MainActivity` from the `PostData` class?

**MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {

    private static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
      }
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("dirtRout")) {
        String directRoute = extras.getString("dirtRout");

        String[] split = directRoute.split(",");
        String direc = split[0];
        String route1 = split[1];
        boolean test = true;
        if (test) {
            test = false;
            System.out.println("test f MainActivity: " + direc + ": "
                    + route1);

            tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDirect);
            tvD.setText(direc);
            tvR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRoute);
            tvR.setText(route1);
        }
    }

}
}
```

**Trackingservice class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
  ...
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        PostData sender = new PostData(TrackingService.this);
                sender.post_data(jSONString, this);
 }
  }
```

**PostData class:**

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    private AsyncTaskCallback callback;
    public PostData(AsyncTaskCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> {
        int route;
        String direction;
  .....
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(String... params) {

                ......
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JSONStore data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), JSONStore.class);

                route = data.getRoute();
                direction = data.getDirection();
  }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer>  result) {
                            if (route != 0) {
                                String directRoute = direction + "," +Integer.toString(route);             
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.getAppContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("dirtRout", directRoute);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the launchMode of your Activity in manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not starting your activity after creating the intent. Get the current activity from the app and call startactivity method.

Comment: Ok i have started the activity abd added the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but nothing happen in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Oncreate is not called? or if you want to have the same activity again change the launch mode of the activity. You can read more on the this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode